# Redirect in primefaces Issue

Tags: javascript, php, html, jsf, primefaces

**Hello i am facing a problem of redirection.**

i have a API which will call when i click on image and it will take user contact number and dial a call from software.

**All things are working perfect** but issue is that, API redirecting to an other page which i do not want.

**I want to show only message of calling**, but focus should remain on same page.

**Here is my xhtml code**:

```
Cell No.
                                            <h:outputText value="#{informationManagerBean.cust.cellNo}" styleClass="textColorChange"/>
                                            Direct Dial

                                            <h:outputLink style="margin: 25px" id="tool_dial"  onclick="PF('callDialog').show();
                                                    {
                                                        return true;
                                                    }" value="http://199.199.333.94/calling.php" >
                                                <img src="Resources/images/dialer.png" alt="NR Letter" align="top" style="margin: 25px"/>
                                                <f:param name="cli"  value="#{informationManagerBean.cust.cellNo}"  />
                                                <f:param name="userid"  value="000001"  />
                                            </h:outputLink>
                                            <p:dialog id="callDialog1" onShow="myFunction();" onHide="myStopFunction();"  header="Calling..."
                                                      width="200px" widgetVar="callDialog"
                                                      position="center" draggable="true" resizable="false" closable="false"
                                                      closeOnEscape="true" appendTo="@(body)" modal="true">


                                            </p:dialog>
```

**here is java Script:**

```
<script>
        var myVar;

        function myFunction()
        {
            myVar = setTimeout(function() {
                PF('callDialog').hide()
            }, 3000);
        }

        function myStopFunction()
        {
            clearTimeout(myVar);
        }

    </script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `onclick="PF('callDialog').show(); return false;"`? `return false` suppresses further actions i.e. goto href.

Comment: @ Holger in outlin i used it, if i use false it will not dial call, only show message

Comment: Ah, sorry, calling.php performs the call....

Comment: `<p:commandLink actionListener="#{mybean.mycallFn()}"  ajax="true" partialSubmit="true" process="@this" oncomplete="PF('callDialog').show()"/>`  and in mybean.mycallFn() you use URLConnection like in the answer

Comment: @Holger like the answer?

Comment: Yes, below is one answer.

Comment: not get the answer

Comment: This is, how you can trigger the dialer from within you bean:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests

Comment: @Holger please write method the url i mentioned and process the question, i am not getting properly. i will remain thankful to you please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with such a function you can trigger your dialer out of your bean

```
public int doCall(String cli, String userid) {
  HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://199.199.333.94/calling.php?cli="+cli+"&userid="+userid).openConnection();
  conn.setDoOutput(false);
  int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
  conn.disconnect();
  return responseCode;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `h:outputLink` is supposed to redirect to another uri. I would suggest you call the REST api on http://199.199.333.94/calling.php from a managed bean to which you can refer via `p:commandLink` or `p:commandButton`. The ajax calls will prevent redirection to the api's uri.

Edit:

See the following for examples on making http calls from java
[How to use java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

Primefaces commandLink https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/button/commandLink.xhtml

Comment: would you please give me example how to call it?